# Is 1/8W resistor good in this circuit

Tags: resistors, circuit-design

The connectors lead to 74HC595 shift register output pins, controlled by arduino. LEDs are rated at 30mA. This is only a part of a chain - there are 3 chains (for 3 shift registers), each chain contains 8 LEDs and each chain is diffrend colour.
Is there a way I could use 1/8 W (125mW) resistor in this circuit. If so what value would it need to be rated at.
[image]

Comment: What is the voltage across the resistor? Multiply that by the current (in amps) and you will have the power dissipated by the resistor. (You probably need different resistors for the different colours as the LEDs will have different voltage drops.) This may help: [Current Limiting Resistor Calculator for Leds](http://ledcalc.com/).

Comment: I know how to calculet resistance values. I just want to know, if i could use a 1/8 W resistor. As i already made a pcb an now realised that 1/4 W is not going to fit becouse lead holes are too close together.

Comment: If the power dissipated by the resistor is less than 1/8 W, then you can use it. Hint: you probably want to run the LEDs at less than 30 mA.

Comment: You could always increase the resistance value to dissipate less, will also decrease "brightness", but lets consider 220 Ohms. 74HC595 , lets consider 6V as max V, according to [datasheet from TI](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/sn74hc595.pdf), LED voltage drop 0.7 V, 5.3*5.3/220 = 127mW ~ 1/8W, so just about at the limit. 5.3V/220 --> running leds at 24mA

Comment: Hc595 absolute max current is 70mA. At 30mA per led, it won’t be hard to exceed that figure.

Answer (score 1):

In the comments OP has said they are able to calculate the resistor values.

Once you have those, all you need to do is work out the power through the resistor. You will already know voltage and current. That gives you values for Voltage, Current and Resistance. Use those values to determine the power. If the answer is less than 125mW, then the resistors are fine to use. If they are above, then they should not be used.